# Lower branch of Lambert W function in mathematica

Tags: special-functions

I am interested in values of the Lambert W function, which is defined as the solution to the equation
$
z = W(z) e^{W(z)} .
$
The solution is not, however, single-valued, but branches into two solutions for $z < 0$. See for example the first figure in [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

[image: branches of the Lambert function]

In *Mathematica*, I can get the part corresponding to the upper branch of the solution with `ProductLog[z]` and even different branches of it on the complex plane with `ProductLog[k, z]`. However, I don't find any way of computing the values of the lower branch of the solution to the equation above, i.e. the function that is, in the Wikipedia article, denoted as $W_{-1}(z)$. Is there a way to compute values of this function in *Mathematica*?

Comment: If, in MMA, `k = 0` corresponds to the principal value, is `ProductLog[-1, z]` not the right thing? I've not looked it into this at all closely, just thinking out loud. Also, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely right. How stupid of me to miss this. I tried indices k=1,2,..., got some complex result and concluded that this is not what I want. Indeed, k=-1 seems to be the way to go (although I don't really understand this indexing).

Comment: I'm not sure about it either...I've turned my comment into an answer for you :-)

Comment: The indexing of the Lambert function $W_k(z)$ is analogous to the branches of the logarithm $\log(z)+2\pi i k$, with $k=0$ being the principal branches for both, and the positively-indexed branches being "stacked" on top of the principal branch, and similarly for the negatively-indexed ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer, `ProductLog` can take two arguments, `k` and `z`, namely:

```
ProductLog[k, z]
```

There's some information to be found under the *Details & Options* of the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html), but instead I turned to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), which has this to say on the matter:

> The plot above shows the function along the real axis. The principal
>   value of the Lambert W-function is implemented in Mathematica as
>   `ProductLog[z]`. Different branches of the function are available in
>   Mathematica as `ProductLog[k, z]`, where `k` is any integer and `k = 0`
>   corresponds to the principal value. Although undocumented,
>   `LambertW[k, z]` autoevaluates to `ProductLog[k, z]` in Mathematica.

Hence, if `k = 0` gives the principal value, I think that using `ProductLog[-1, z]` should be the solution you're after for $W_{-1}(z)$.

I'm not sure why the documentation isn't as clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    lst = Select[
  Table[{z, (FindRoot[w + Log[w] == Log[z], {w, -1000, -1}, 
        Method -> "Secant", AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // 
       Chop)[[1, 2]]}, {z, -0.5, -0.009, 0.002}], Im[#[[2]]] == 0 &];
```

which gives the list with the structure `{z,W}`. This plots the list

```
    ListPlot[Select[lst, Im[#[[2]]] == 0 &], 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.1}, {-6, 1}}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["z", 16, Italic], Style["W", 16, Italic]}]
```

It should look like follows:
[image]

There is a still more simple approach to this question. Just let us plot the function using the `ParametricPlot`:

```
 ParametricPlot[{W*Exp[W], W}, {W, -6, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.1}, {-6, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 0.6, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["z", 16, Italic], Style["W", 16, Italic]}]
```

Obviously, it should look very close to the first one:
[image]

If you need a table of the solution (e.g., `z`versus `W`you can make the list using the same idea:

```
lst2 = Table[{W*Exp[W], W} // N, {W, -6, 0, 0.3}]
```

yielding

```
(*  {{-0.0148725, -6.}, {-0.019072, -5.7}, {-0.0243895, -5.4}, \
{-0.0310934, -5.1}, {-0.0395028, -4.8}, {-0.0499905, -4.5}, \
{-0.0629814, -4.2}, {-0.0789435, -3.9}, {-0.0983654, -3.6}, \
{-0.121714, -3.3}, {-0.149361, -3.}, {-0.181455, -2.7}, {-0.217723, \
-2.4}, {-0.257158, -2.1}, {-0.297538, -1.8}, {-0.334695, -1.5}, \
{-0.361433, -1.2}, {-0.365913, -0.9}, {-0.329287, -0.6}, {-0.222245, \
-0.3}, {0., 0.}}   *)
```

I made a small step to have it short.

Have fun!

Comment: I'm sure this works, but unfortunately blochwave gave a much easier solution in the comments :). Thanks anyway.